# Influxdb x measurements over one measurement with a tag of x values

Tags: influxdb

A web application has 4 types of users. I want to track the response time of  each type of user.

- Solution 1 : Create a measurement with tag of user type which gives me a cardinality of 4.
- Solution 2: Create a table for each type of user which creates also a cardinality of 4 (one coming from each table).

Supposing I am not interested on comping the data of the users. So issuing multiple queries on influxdb is not a problem.

What is the outcome of each solution in terms of performance, storage and memory? Which one is the influxdb way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go with solution 1:

> https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#don-t-encode-data-in-measurement-names
>
> Don’t encode data in measurement names
>
> In general, taking this step will simplify your queries. InfluxDB queries merge data that fall within the same measurement; it’s better to differentiate data with tags than with detailed measurement names.

Comment: This is the correct answer based on the documenation. However due to the finite amount of tags due to the inverted memory index, sometimes I might go with manny measurements on different influxdb instances.